# Warlock Handbook for 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

Is there a 3.5e style handbook for the 5e Warlock yet?
3.5e Style meaning a clear structure with ratings and comments to different abilities and build options.
It seems my Google-fu isn't up to the task of finding one unfortunatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm unaware of what the format for 3.5 handbooks were, but this follows the 4e handbook style for class builds: [Blade, Book, and Chain: the Warlock Guide](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?469128-GUIDE-Blade-Book-and-Chain-the-Warlock-Guide).

That thread also links to [a google doc version of the Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXSp1_deob6MYdNJVb09JoSBdT_InvgZ4cB6UBfOHkQ/edit?usp=sharing) which is likely more up to date than the forum thread.

In general, at this early stage of the game you are most likely to find such handbooks in the WotC section of the EnWorld forums, since even if it exists in another forum, people there tend to link to them if they are of good quality.